# VSC Latex-Workshop clean up output directory

Tags: ide, build-system

I try to have a cleaned up output directory after build but it doesn't work. Is anyone using this VS Code Extension and could tell me what's wrong with my settings?

```
{
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 80,
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "same",
    "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "./build",
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.cleanAndRetry.enabled": true,
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onBuilt",
    "latex-workshop.latex.clean.subfolder.enabled": true,
    "latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes": [ "*.aux" ]
}
```

It's building into the `/build` directory and I'd like to delete everything but the PDF files afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  I guess you need to extend the last line to include other extensions, but that is potentially a long list.  Cf. https://gist.github.com/kogakure/149016 (but I am not sure why `.dvi` is on that list)

Comment: without running vs code I am having to guess at suggestions however latex-workshop.latex.clean.subfolder.enabled implies subfolders of outdir but you have set outdir to build ! for some hints on a related issue see https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/530 where the command assumes outdir is main then filetypes are given as build/*

Comment: I understand that this question is not directly latex related, but would it fit somewhere else?